# AngularJS, ui-router: Inject $stateParams into NOT anonymous function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection, angular-ui-router, angular-ui

I want to inject $stateParams into a NOT anonymous function using ui-router with AngularJS.

Using a anonymous function, I would usually do this:

```
.state('app.users', {
     url: '/users/:param1/:param2',
     params: {
         ...
     },
     templateUrl: function($stateParams) { // <----- Here is the anonymous function
         ... do something ...
     },
     resolve: {
         ...
     }
})
```

What I want to do is replace the function($stateParams) by a function I have set before. Something like:

```
// Here is my function being set before the code, 
// so I can use the same function in multiple states without duplicating code
var myFunction = function (myParam, $stateParams) { 
    ... do something ...
}

... setting the routes on ui-router ...

.state('app.users', {
    ...
    templateUrl: myFunction(myParam, $stateParams), // <--- I want to set that function here, injecting the "$stateParams" at the same time
    ...
}
```

I thought of one way to solve this: create a anonymous function, then inside that anonymous function I can call `myFunction` with the $stateParams  injected. But that doesn't feel right.

My question is:
 How does the $stateParams get injected into the anonymous function? Is there any way I can inject that into `myFunction` without creating another anonymous function?

Comment: What is the purpose of the function you want to use for templatUrl?

Comment: @mindparse So I can use the same function in multiple states without duplicating code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is appropriate to do

```
 templateUrl: myFunction,
```

Angular uses either [$injector.invoke](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#invoke) or [$injector.instantiate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#instantiate) for dependency injection (it is the former in this case), both use [$injector.annotate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$injector#annotate) internally to figure out what dependencies should be injected. `$injector.annotate` [parses](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.4.8/src/auto/injector.js#L100) the signature of called function with regular expression and gets the names of dependencies.

It is also necessary to provide [annotation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/di#dependency-annotation) for `myFunction` in order for it to be annotated properly in minified JS.

Comment: If I don't pass any other arguments in `myFunction` besides the $stateParams it works great! But it still doesn't work if I try to pass an argument like: `function myFunction (firstArgument, $stateParams)` any thoughts on this?

Comment: Forgot to mention that `templateUrl: myFunction('users', $stateParams),` doesn't work, and that is the problem. And I can't let the second parameter blank either

Comment: The example which works (but doesn't feel right) that I mentioned in my question: `templateUrl: function ($stateParams) { return myFunction('users', $stateParams); },`

Comment: ^^^ It is exactly what should be done in this case if you need to pass an additional parameter to myFunction, there is nothing wrong with it. Yes, other variations shouldn't work. `myFunction` is a function, while `myFunction(...)` is a result which is returned by this function, they are not interchangeable.